# Run python script from Laravel 5.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, laravel-5, process

I am using Laravel 5.8 and need to run python script from it

I installed python3.6 and added it to the windows path it is working fine from command line

```
C:\Users\mmm>python -V
Python 3.6.6

C:\Users\mmm>
```

from laravel controller I added below code

```
$process = new Process("python.exe 'path/to/scipt.py'");
        $process->run();

        // executes after the command finishes
        if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
            throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
        }

dd(json_decode($process->getOutput(), true));
```

when call this api from postman it return the below error

```
Error Output:
================
'python.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
"""
```

any suggestions how to solve this problem ?

Comment: remove the ".exe" from the Process object creation?

Comment: I already did but didn't work, same error

Comment: Ok, just jumped on the discrepancy between the error and your question description there. So it sounds like the recognized paths are not the same in your windows terminal and from php (I don't use windows for development so I don't know how the paths are set there). But it should work with using the full path to your python.exe if that is a possible option for this case.